# Create a stacked bar chart with grouping using pandas and bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

My dataset is like:

```
   Count     Date   teams sex
    39  2017/12/28    a   m
    26  2019/12/28    b   f
    3   2016/12/28    c   f
    8   2017/12/28    d   m
    1   2019/12/28    f   f
    22  2018/12/28    a   m
    26  2016/12/29    b   m
```

I want a stacked chart with sex as stacks and grouped across teams ,
each day, using bokeh plot.

I found an answer but its using old bokeh plot and is deprecated as of now.

```
from bokeh.charts import Bar, output_file, show

p = Bar(df, label='date', values='count', stack='class',  group='user',
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bar` was deprecated a long time ago, and subsequently removed completely. It cannot be used with any recent versions I would highly recommend against using it with old versions either.

Instead, there is an entire chapter of the user's guide that describes how to make all sorts of bar charts, including stacked and grouped bar charts: [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)

To create a stacked, grouped bar chart you need to specify [nested categories](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#nested-categories) together with [`vbar_stack`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacked)

A complete example is [in the docs](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#stacked-and-grouped) but I have reproduced an abridged version here as well:

```
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure

factors = [
    ("Q1", "jan"), ("Q1", "feb"), ("Q1", "mar"),
    ("Q2", "apr"), ("Q2", "may"), ("Q2", "jun"),
    ("Q3", "jul"), ("Q3", "aug"), ("Q3", "sep"),
    ("Q4", "oct"), ("Q4", "nov"), ("Q4", "dec"),

]

regions = ['east', 'west']

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=factors,
    east=[ 5, 5, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 6, 9 ],
    west=[ 5, 7, 9, 4, 5, 4, 7, 7, 7, 6, 6, 7 ],
))

p = figure(x_range=FactorRange(*factors), plot_height=250,
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar_stack(regions, x='x', width=0.9, alpha=0.5, color=["blue", "red"], source=source,
             legend=[value(x) for x in regions])

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: but how will i do it using directly dataframe as the deprecated  library?

Comment: You can put the pandas series (columns) in the bokeh data source instead of lists. There are also ways to initialize Bokeh data sources with dataframes that may apply. All of that is described and demonstrated in the docs I linked.